# Heart of a bounded $t$-structure on the derived category of coherent sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, derived-categories, coherent-sheaves, t-structure

Let $X$ be an elliptic curve and $D(X)$ the bounded derived category of $Coh(X)$, coherent sheaves on $X$. If $(D^{\leq 0}, D^{>0})$ is a bounded $t$-structure, then can we already say that the heart $D^{\leq 0}\cap D^{>0}[1]$ is equivalent to $Coh(X)$ (by a shift) ?

Comment: I'm not an expert in this area, but if you're interested in questions about what one can say about general bounded $t$-structures on familiar categories, one example of work I happen to be aware of is Antieau, Gepner, and Heller's [K-theoretic obstructions to bounded $t$-structures](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.07207). From the title, they might not address your actual question, but perhaps some consdierations they make might be relevant.

Comment: There's also a recognition principle due to Lurie -- see [Prop 1.3.3.7 of HA](http://people.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/papers/HA.pdf#page=79) which might only be directly applicable in the affine case. This was used to great effect for example by [Gheorghe, Wang, and Xu](https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.09290) in motivic homotopy theory, with applications to recent breakthroughs in computing homotopy groups of spheres.

Comment: Unless I'm being stupid, [perverse sheaves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-structure#Perverse_sheaves) give an example of a non-standard $t$-structure with the same heart. So I guess what I'm driving at is that there _is_ a kind of principle that $t$-structures are "sometimes" determined by their hearts (contrary to your hope that lots of $t$-structures have the same heart) but that this principle is not at all universally true, so I find your question interesting.

Answer (score 7):

One can construct t-structures on the bounded derived category of coherent sheaves on a smooth projective curve (or higher-dimensional variety) by tilting, see [Bayer's notes](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Eabayer/dc-lecture-notes.pdf), Prop. 3.6.1, and the corresponding hearts are not shifts of each other, because the tilt shifts some objects but not all of them.

Another way to obtain t-structures is to apply autoequivalences of the derived category to the standard heart, see Exercise 11 in Bayer's notes for the elliptic curve case.

Generally t-structures on bounded derived categories of coherent sheaves are studied in the context of the Bridegland stability conditions, and stability conditions for elliptic curves have been classified in Section 9 of [Bridgeland's original paper](http://www.tom-bridgeland.staff.shef.ac.uk/publications/pub9.pdf).

Comment: Oh, in the original question is was asked whether the equivalence between hearts is given by a shift. However, it is certainly interesting to know whether all these hearts are equivalent "abstractly". Do you know this?

Comment: I think it's a much more subtle and not so well studied question whether various hearts are equivalent as abelian categories. This is definitely false for $\mathbf{P}^1$ (standard heart has infinitely many simples, but the Kronecker quiver has two), but I don't know about elliptic curve and the tilted hearts.

Comment: This paper is exactly how i came up with the question. More precisely when i tried to understand the proof of the fact (in the Proof of Theorem 9.1.) that indecomposable implies semistable he uses things (serre duality, $Ext^1_{Coh(X)}(B,A) = Hom_{D(X)}^1(B,A))$ that i only know when the heart is already $Coh(X)$ (by a shift).

Comment: @user12344321: Serre duality is a statement about objects in derived categories, it's not for a specific heart, see e.g. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.09115.pdf,  1.6.